# React: Ternary operation in JSX produces "Unexpected token" error

Tags: reactjs, ternary-operator

I am trying to check if an array is not empty before i start showing it. Here is my code:

```
{ item2.user.entities.url !== null 
              ? ({item2.user.entities.url.urls.map((item3,index3) => {
                    return(
                        <a href={item3.expanded_url} target='_blank'>{item3.expanded_url}</a>
                      )
                    })
                  })
              : null
            }
```

I am not sure. its showing error

```
babel.min.js:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token, expected , (187:23) 
  186 |           { item2.user.entities.url !== null 
> 187 |               ? ({item2.user.entities.url.urls.map((item3,index3) => {
      |                        ^
  188 |                     return(
  189 |                         <a href={item3.expanded_url} target='_blank'>{item3.expanded_url}</a>
  190 |                       )
    at t.le.raise (babel.min.js:8)
    at t.Z.unexpected (babel.min.js:7)
    at t.Z.expect (babel.min.js:7)
    at t.se.parseObj (babel.min.js:8)
    at t.se.parseExprAtom (babel.min.js:8)
    at t.parseExprAtom (babel.min.js:9)
    at t.se.parseExprSubscripts (babel.min.js:8)
    at t.se.parseMaybeUnary (babel.min.js:7)
    at t.se.parseExprOps (babel.min.js:7)
    at t.se.parseMaybeConditional (babel.min.js:7)
```

Unable to understand whats the error

Comment: ? ({ item2.user.entities.url.urls.map to ? item2.user.entities.url.urls.map
  remove this ({ }) and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `{}`

```
const a = item2 => {
  item2.user.entities.url !== null
    ? item2.user.entities.url.urls.map((item3, index3) => {
        return (
          <a href={item3.expanded_url} target="_blank">
            {item3.expanded_url}
          </a>
        );
      })
    : null;
};
```

Comment: great detection

Comment: just use prettier!

Comment: is it a sublime text plugin can put the link

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi https://github.com/danreeves/sublime-prettier here you are

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a JSX expression (`{}`) inside another JSX expression.

You need to wrap your second JSX expression with an element like a `<div>`:

```js
{item2.user.entities.url !== null ? (
    <div>
        {item2.user.entities.url.urls.map((item3, index3) => (
            <a href={item3.expanded_url} target='_blank'> 
                {item3.expanded_url}
            </a>
        )}
    </div>
 ) : null}
```

Or make it a single expression:

```js
{item2.user.entities.url !== null ? item2.user.entities.url.urls.map((item3, index3) => (
    <a href={item3.expanded_url} target='_blank'> 
        {item3.expanded_url}
    </a>
 ) : null}
```